# Почему вылетает NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, loader

Инициализирую `recyclerview` с помощью `androidannotaions`

```
@ViewById(R.id.fragment_peoples_recyclerview)
RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

Сама ошибка такая

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
```

Полный код такой

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_listview)
public class PeopleFragment extends Fragment {

    @ViewById(R.id.fragment_peoples_recyclerview)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private People peoples;
    private String name;

    @AfterViews
    public void ready() {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        getAllPeoplesRest(recyclerView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadRecordings();
    }

    private void loadRecordings() {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<People>>() {
            @Override
            public Loader<List<People>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
                final AsyncTaskLoader<List<People>> loader = new AsyncTaskLoader<List<People>>(getActivity()) {
                    @Override
                    public List<People> loadInBackground() {
                        return People.getAllPeoples();
                    }
                };
                loader.forceLoad();
                return loader;
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<People>> loader, List<People> data) {
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new PeoplesAdapter(data));
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<People>> loader) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Background
    public void getAllPeoplesRest(View v) {
        if (!NetworkStatusChecker.isNetworkAvailable(getContext())) {
            Snackbar.make(v, R.string.internet_is_not_found, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }


        RestService restService = new RestService();
        ArrayList<PeoplesModel> peoplesModel;
        try {
            peoplesModel = restService.getPeoples();
        } catch (RetrofitError e) {
            Snackbar.make(v, R.string.internet_is_not_found, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        for (PeoplesModel people : peoplesModel) {
            peoples = new People();
            name = people.getName()+people.getSurName();
            peoples.setName(name);
            if (!peoples.exists()) {
                peoples.insert();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в другом файле, в androidannotations есть такая особенность, что надо ставить знак нижнего подчеркивания после имени файла, к примеру MainActivity_, MyFragment_ и т.д.